# Problema Javascript Onlick

Tags: javascript

Buenas tengo este detalle, por medio de un boton agrego tr a una tabla entonces, para poder eliminar los tr si no los necesito, uso onclick="Eliminar('+nro+')", pero en este caso quisiera colocar onclick="Eliminar(tv'+nro+')", en donde tv seria como si colocaramos una cadena de texto al parcer tengo problema con las comillas simples y dobles y no me lo reconoce, si alguien pudiera ayudarme con esta parte lo agradeceria. Gracias de ante Mano.

Comment: Hola @reyesg. ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta e incluir el código de lo que has intentado?

Answer (score 0):

Al momento de ejecutarse, js entiende tv como una variable.

Asigna una variable temporal y luego concatenala

```
var temp = "Eliminar('td" + nro + " ')";
```

Luego al concatenar

```
'onclick=' + temp
```

Por otra parte, puedes usar comillas simples como texto si utilizas lo siguiente

```
\'
```

```
onclick="Eliminar(\'td' + nro + '\')"
```

Comment: si uso esto \', como quedaria entonces?? porq ando probando y no pasa nada .. lo puse asi onclick="Eliminar(\'td'+nro+')"  y en el html me aparece asi Eliminar('td 1 )

Comment: Edité la respuesta, al usar \' indicas que se utilizará ese caracter como string y no es un delimitador de la cadena